# Symfony2 Routing issue with multiple bundle and configuration levels

Tags: symfony, routes

I've a project with multiple bundles arranged per domain of activities in Symfony2.The project is running under the following domain one my local WAMP : Agapp.local with the following `app/config/routing.yml`

```
ag_app:
    resource: "@AgAppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

ag_apsa:
    resource: "@AgApsaBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /apsa

ag_training:
    resource: "@AgTrainingBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /training

ag_intern:
    resource: "@AgInternBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /parents/intern

ag_parents:
    resource: "@AgParentsBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /parents

ag_circo:
    resource: "@AgCircoBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /circo

ag_ecole:
    resource: "@AgEcoleBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /ecole
```

The AgApsaBundle has the following main routing file:

```
ag_apsa_homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AgrementApsaBundle:Apsa:index }

ag_apsa:
    resource: "@AgrementApsaBundle/Resources/config/routing/apsa.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

And here is the AgApsaBundle.yml content:

```
apsa:
   path:     /
   defaults: { _controller: "AgrementApsaBundle:Apsa:index" }

apsa_show:
    path:    /{id}/show
    defaults: { _controller: "AgApsaBundle:Apsa:show" }

apsa_new:
    path:     /new
    defaults: { _controller: "AgApsaBundle:Apsa:new" }

apsa_create:
    path:     /create
    defaults: { _controller: "AgApsaBundle:Apsa:create" }
    requirements: { _method: post }

apsa_edit:
    path:     /{id}/edit
    defaults: { _controller: "AgApsaBundle:Apsa:edit" }

apsa_update:
    path:     /{id}/update
    defaults: { _controller: "AgApsaBundle:Apsa:update" }
    requirements: { _method: post|put }

apsa_delete:
    path:    /{id}/delete
    defaults: { _controller: "AgApsaBundle:Apsa:delete" }
    requirements: { _method: post|delete }
```

The AppKernel info :

`new Ag\Metiers\Etab\EcoleBundle\AgEcoleBundle(),
            new Ag\Metiers\Etab\CircoBundle\AgCircoBundle(),
            new Ag\Metiers\Parents\ParentsBundle\AgParentsBundle(),
            new Ag\Metiers\Parents\InternBundle\AgInternBundle(),
            new Ag\Metiers\Training\TrainingBundle\AgTrainingBundle(),
            new Ag\Metiers\TrainingApsaBundle\AgApsaBundle(),
            new Ag\AppBundle\AgAppBundle(),`

All the routes are well registered and listed ,as confirmed by the `router:debug` command.
However, trying to access the `AgApp.local/apsa` or any other route related to the Apsa bundle, it returns a '*No data received Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data*.', while the log registers that a macthed route was found.  On the opposite, trying a `AgApp.local/apsa/parents` will throw a 404 error.
You may find the log trace [here](http://pastebin.com/j8WSHHVs)

Am i missing something in the routing configuration?

Comment: Are you sure the log is matching the right route? Look for the kernel info level of symfony to check the matched route. Since you are using WAMP I can imagine you have some problems with rewriting!

Comment: `[2015-12-14 15:39:35] request.INFO: Matched route "ag_apsa_homepage" (parameters: "_controller": "Ag\Metiers\Training\ApsaBundle\Controller\ApsaController::indexAction", "_route": "ag_apsa_homepage") [] []`  Yes, they're defined appropriately in the kernel (see updated question)

Comment: Can you try access `AgApp.local/apsa/` with the ending slash and tell me if you land in your action?

Comment: It returns the same result , as in the route is found wth the appropriate Action (from the Logs) but nothing is returned

Comment: Ok. as I see you really have a configuration issue since you have multiple prefixes in each level of your configurations. I would recommend you to move the specific route to `app/config/routing.yml` just for test, and then you try to move it to the bundle specific configuration. Remeber to comment/remove the bundle reference while testing this

Comment: When i move the specific route inside the bundle i get a 404 error on the route. However, should i put the route into the `app\config` it returns nothing (As the question above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After , more research i found that the routes themselves were not the cause of the issue .But rather Doctrine, you can find the related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335964/doctrine-entity-manager-causing-page-to-break)