# Doctrine entity manager causing page to break

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, twig

I'm  new to Symfony2 and trying to display a page listing items of an entity. However, once i use the code below the page breaks with a "No data received error" or "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" leading me to think that my routes were not working and raising the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268456/symfony2-routing-issue-with-multiple-bundle-and-configuration-levels) but the issue was related to Doctrine:

```
    public function indexAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('ApsaBundle:Apsa')->findAll();

    return $this->render('ApsaBundle:Apsa:index.html.twig', array(
                'entities' => $entities,
    ));
```

However, this simple function displays the page :

```
    public function indexAction() {
             return $this->render('ApsaBundle:Apsa:index.html.twig');
   }
```

i'll be glad to know how to go about debugging this doctrine issue.Below the twig use to display the page

```
{% extends ::base.html.twig %}
{% block body -%}
    Apsa list

    <table class="records_list">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Titre</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for entity in entities %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#">{{ entity.id }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ entity.titre }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.description }}</td>
                <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">show</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">edit</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

        <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                Create a new entry
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    {% endblock %}
```

May you find the link to the zipped project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qtbq7e7k7z92pzo/AgrementEPS.7z?dl=0)

Comment: how many records would fetch the query?

Comment: At the moments 0, as i haven't populated the table.

Comment: how many records are in the table? the table is empty?

Comment: yes the table is empty et the moment

Comment: can you post the code of the twig page? or can you disable the rendering of the records in it?

Comment: Updated the question with the twig.

Comment: possibily a typo in this line `{{ entity.titre }}` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98243/discussion-between-raymond-and-matteo).

Comment: After recommendation from http://stackoverflow.com/users/5437246/scoolnico i was able to run and display the content on the `http://localhost:8888/apsa/`  but stil not on `web1.local/app_dev.php/apsa/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably due to a bad WAMP configuration.

I invite you to try with the build-in symfony server available by this command line:

`php app/console server:run`

Comment: Indeed the project runs fine under the built in symfony server. I have to figure out what is wrong with my WAMP config. Thanks