# Symfony2 App working with built in server but not under Apache Virtualhost

Tags: php, apache, symfony, wamp, wampserver

This question is a follow up from this one on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335964/doctrine-entity-manager-causing-page-to-break) , i've an app setup on WAMP 2.5(64 bit) on Win 7 (64bit) with the following settings :

- Apache : 2.4.9
- PHP : 5.5.12
- MySQL : 5.6.17
- Symfony 2.7

When ran under the Virtualhost only the page not requiring a DB access get displayed including the inner pages however when a page require to load some data it's throw a **`Error 'ERR_CONNEXION_RESET'`**.
However, when ran under the built-in server  i'm able to display all the pages and go through the app with success.
The Apache log doesn't give any meaningful information except that the child process had to restart.
On the opposite, the Window Event Viewer give the following error:

`Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version : 2.4.9.0, time stamp: 0x5667fd57
Faulting module name: php5ts.dll, version : 5.5.12.0, time stamp: 0x56d7bf4a
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset : 0x000000000013b7d4
Faulting process id: 0x1090
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1c616b8aabd41
Faulting application path: D:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.9.0\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: D:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.9.0\bin\php5ts.dll
Report Id: fa0b0233-3209-11e6-9741-c03fd507633c`

Here is my virtualhost config for the WAMP server :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "d:/wamp64/www/Agrem/web"
ServerName agrem.local
ErrorLog "logs/agrem.local-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/agrem.local-access.log" common
<Directory  "d:/wamp64/www/Agre/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I've already tried the solution found on :

1. [Symfony2/Wamp issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347325/is-it-posible-to-use-symfony-2-0-with-wamp-server-reliably)
2. [Symfony2/VirtualHosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962054/symfony-2-on-virtual-hosts)
3. [Symfony2 Configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html)
4. Re-install of all [VC](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) distributions and test again various WAMP configuration.
5. Test again EasyPHP with the same result.

I'm would like to understand why it runs under the *Built in Server* and not as a *VirtualHost* or *Project under the WebServer Config*

**Update**
 After a try on a new 'bare' pc with EasyPHP i was able to have more details in the log regarding the issue.
The restart/failure , was linked to the [parent-child-process-exited-with-status-3221225477](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1138269/1374947) error.
I added the following lines at the end of my '`httpd.conf`' file of the running Apache server based on the explanation given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34452918/1374947):

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadStackSize 8888888
</IfModule>
```

So far i'm no more having the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by this statement _My Symfony2 app is configured to run on PHP 5.3.3_ Symfont 2 has a minimum requirement of PHP5.5.9 according to [their requirements page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html)

Comment: I meant in my `composer.json` for the project  ,it's set to work on PHP 5.3.3 and Symfony 2.4 LTS   ` "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "=2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",`